# Circumference and sphere with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I have big troubles trying to draw the next picture in latex, could you help me? I´m desperate, it´s for my bachelor thesis...

[image]
The idea is to make a nice picture of the circumference´s decomposition following the last photo.

I need the same thing but  this time with the sphere :

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can play with polar coordinates and `arc` to get the circle sectors.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
  \newcommand\angStart{30}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw[cyan] (180+\angStart:1.1) arc (180+\angStart:-\angStart:1.1);
  \draw[black!30!green] (180-\angStart:1.2) arc (180-\angStart:360+\angStart:1.2);
  \draw[orange] (180-\angStart:1.3) arc (180-\angStart:180+\angStart:1.3);
  \draw[black!30!orange] (-\angStart:1.3) arc (-\angStart:+\angStart:1.3);
  \node[cyan,right] at (180:1){\textsf{U1}};
  \node[black!30!green,left] at (0:1){\textsf{U2}};
  \node[orange,left] at (180:1.3){\textsf{W1}};
  \node[black!30!orange,right] at (0:1.3){\textsf{W2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, line join=round]
  \newcommand\angStart{30}
  \newcommand\zfactor{0.25}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw[dashed] (0:1) arc (0:180:1 and 1*\zfactor);\draw (180:1) arc (180:360:1 and 1*\zfactor);
  %%
  \draw[gray,dashed] (0:1.2) arc (0:180:1.2 and 1.2*\zfactor);
  \fill[fill=cyan,opacity=0.4] (-\angStart:1.2) arc (-\angStart:180+\angStart:1.2) 
  arc (180+3:360-3:{1.2*cos(\angStart)} and {1.2*\zfactor*cos(\angStart)}) -- cycle;
  \draw[gray] (180:1.2) arc (180:360:1.2 and 1.2*\zfactor);
  \draw[gray] (-\angStart:1.2) arc (-\angStart:180+\angStart:1.2) 
  arc (180+3:360-3:{1.2*cos(\angStart)} and {1.2*\zfactor*cos(\angStart)}) -- cycle;
  %%
  \draw[dashed] (0:1.4) arc (0:180:1.4 and 1.4*\zfactor);
  \fill[black!30!green,opacity=0.4] (180-\angStart:1.4) arc (180-\angStart:360+\angStart:1.4)
  arc (-3:-180+3:{1.4*cos(\angStart)} and {1.4*\zfactor*cos(\angStart)}) -- cycle;
  \draw (180:1.4) arc (180:360:1.4 and 1.4*\zfactor);
  \draw[] (180-\angStart:1.4) arc (180-\angStart:360+\angStart:1.4)
  arc (-3:-180+3:{1.4*cos(\angStart)} and {1.4*\zfactor*cos(\angStart)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]